# Does the hour of the day and the position on the sun have any influences on the formation of a hurricane?

Tags: meteorology, tropical-cyclone, earth-observation

I am writing an essay and cannot find if a hurricane is influenced by the position of the sun or the hour of the day.

Comment: Searching for *timescale hurricane formation* or *lifecycle hurricane* can give you a start. I first thought it could not have an influence, but it appears hurricanes can form within a day.

Comment: I googled [this](https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/joc.3744): "In three time zones, onset of intensification (7.7 m s−1 [15 kt]/24 h) appeared to
be most likely shortly after midnight local time, and least likely shortly before midnight. Cyclogenesis was least frequent
around local midnight, and most likely in the diurnal morning hours."